# How can I turn off motion blur?

Tags: mass-effect-3

I hate motion blur, as my often jerky movements mean that I often can't see what's going on, is there any way to turn off or reduce this effect?

I've looked in the graphics menu but couldn't see anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two ways you can do that.

1. Go to your "My Documents\BioWare\Mass Effect 3\BIOGame\Config" folder and open the file "GamerSettings.ini" in Notepad. Change the line "MotionBlur=True" to "MotionBlur=False" (if it's not there add it under "[SystemSettings]" header).
2. Go to "Mass Effect 3\Binaries" folder (where you installed the game) and run MassEffect3Config.exe - it will let you configure various options, including motion blur.

Source: http://social.bioware.com/forum/1/topic/344/index/9652824/1

Comment: Will doing these cause a ban from the multiplayer servers?

Comment: @Tristan Doing it via method #2 definitely will not (and has the benefit of being easier, too)